# Resume an installer after restarting

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer, bootstrapping, bootstrapper

The installer needs to run the .NET 4 installer (dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe) and Microsoft Surface Toolkit (SurfaceToolkitRuntime.msi). The problem is that the .NET 4 install needs to restart the machine AND the Microsoft Surface Toolkit requires .NET 4 to install.

From looking at other questions I appears I should be using [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) (yes/no?). Is this something that could be done in a batch file?

If I need to use WiX/batch file/other what kind of code performs this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating your software in Visual Studio, you can have the setup project (which creates your MSI installer) [install .NET and other software as prerequisites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77z6b8tz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), saving the reboot prompt until the end. You may have to [create custom bootstrapper packages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for the Surface Toolkit and such, but it's not too difficult and works well.

Comment: Thanks ewall.  After your advice and googling more I know I need to get some bootstrappers made.  

This site gave some code examples on resuming an installer after rebooting:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrsmith/archive/2005/09/02/rebooting-in-the-bootstrapper.aspx

Comment: Ooh, I hadn't seen that page before, but I've got it bookmarked now for future reference!